# How to send value of a variable to database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, rest

I need to store data of a variable to database. I am not using any form in my page. How can we store a value of a variable to database without using a form?

Comment: post your code also?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ajax submit.
On Document read which also means site load completely
On Click or,
On Anything else

```
$(".class").on('click', function(){
event.preventDefault();
// If it's in an input
var getdata = $(".dataclass").val();
// if it's in a span/div
var getdata = $(".spanclass").text();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "path/path/insert.php",
  data: "param="+ getdata,
  success: function(data) {
  if (data == "sent") {
    // Do something if it inserted
  } else {
    // Do something if it don't
  }
    console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

Then the php file (insert.php) should look like this

```
<?php
session_start();
//include connection script
include_once 'connectionscript.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$data = $_POST['param'];
$ins = sprintf("INSERT INTO tb_name(active_date) " .
      "VALUES ('%s'); ",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data),
        mysqli_insert_id($conn));
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $ins)) {
      $i = "sent";
    } else {
      $i = "failed";
    }
    return $i;
  }
?>
```

I Hope this is helpful